# highcharts download/export image with rounded borders

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want highcharts download image to have rounded borders in the image. as I've set rounded border in this fiddle:
[Fiddle, highcharts with rounded borders](http://jsfiddle.net/d4ss486y/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            borderColor: '#EBBA95',
            borderRadius: 20,
            borderWidth: 2,
            type: 'line'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            floating: true,
            align: 'left',
            x: 100,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 70
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.x + ': ' + this.y;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }],
        exporting: {
            enabled: true
        }
    });
});
```

the problem is that when I download the PNG image of this chart from the upper-right menu button, the image does not contain rounded border. please if anyone know tell me that how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like possibly bug, so I reported that to our developers [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4567)

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian sir.